# Tiling triangulated irregular network (TIN)

Tags: tin, vector-tiles, tile-map-service

I want to generate vector tiles for TIN which I created from elevation data. I want to use Tile Map Server (TMS) specification for vector tiles. But I did not understand how tile bounds can be calculated for vector data such as TIN and how quadtree structure can be created for TIN. Any help?

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong but a TIN is not (in the traditional GIS sense) a vector.

Comment: With "TIN" I mean vector terrain data such as quantized mesh